# wordpress json API fetch problem from localhost

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

if I call the json api v2 in wordpress from a local website via fetch, it works without any problems.

```
fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } } )
```

when I call the old json api via fetch I get an error unable to fetch (directly with the browser no problem)

```
fetch('https://example.com/?json=get_page_index&custom_fields=*&dev=1&count=800', { method: 'GET', headers: { 'content-type': 'plain/text' } } )
```

in the network debug tab I see
provisional headers are shown Learn more
application/json: application/json
DNT: 1
Referrer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/87.0.4280.7

What could be the reason.

Comment: Is the space between `?` and `json=...` a typo?

Comment: Also, if you're using the [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin on your project you really should consider stop using it. The plugin was closed on August 2019 due to "security issues."

Comment: i am using the plugin in a local setup, no security issues. the V2 version isn't handy for child parent relations.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the question